# How can I prevent an Element from overflowing outside of its column width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a query form using bootstrap's 12 column grid system (version 3). The layout consists of dropdown menu where a user can select an item.

**The Problem:**
When a user selects a value from  the dropdown menu, the element overflows into the next column. Is there a recommended solution for correcting this?

[image]
[image]

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown>
      <button id="btn-append-to-body" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" uib-dropdown-toggle="">
        {{importTGModal.paramCondition1_selected}} 
        <span class="caret">
        </span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-click="importTGModal.setParamCondition1($event)" uib-dropdown-menu="" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-append-to-body">
        <li role="menuitem" ng-repeat="condition in importTGModal.paramConditions1">
          <a data-value={{condition}}>{{condition}}
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is code ?

Comment: Use css property "overflow:hidden" maybe its help you. Otherwise post your code here so we can understand it better.

Comment: added code per request

Comment: Where is the CSS you used .?

Comment: there is no css i have used, just the native boostrap css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the dropdown is larger than the container column.

Try one of the following:

1- (Recommended) Put the dropdown and the input text in same column

2- Make the column of the dropdown bigger. Like `col-md-6`

3- (Not Recommended) Bootstrap class `.btn` adds `white-space: nowrap;`. Set it to `white-spsace: normal` for this button, so if the button has long text (bigger than the column) the text will break to next line. Like so:

```
<button id="btn-append-to-body" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" uib-dropdown-toggle="" style="white-space: normal;">
```